# How to edit or create roles in Proxmox VE?

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, openvz, proxmox

How can I create Roles or edit them with specific privileges in Proxmox VE ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution:

```
pveum roleadd PVEDatastorePowerUser -privs "Datastore.AllocateSpace Datastore.Audit Datastore.AllocateTemplate"
```

Source : http://forum.proxmox.com/threads/8418-Permissions-and-roles